# SSIS connection to Odata issue

Tags: ssis, odata

I am trying to connect `SSIS` to my `sharepoint` list /folder, I tried to use `Odata` source, but I am facing a problem of authentication.

Can you help me guys how to configure the `Odata`?

I get following error:

[image: error image]

Thanks

Comment: Please add the image as an attachment to your post.

Comment: [How to configure OData SSIS Connection for SharePoint Online](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-configure-odata-ssis-connection-for-sharepoint-online/)